# How to undo soft delete in Sequelize.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize.js in paranoid mode in my node.js project and while the soft deletion works as expected in finding and deleting data, i'm having trouble finding a way to undelete soft deleted rows.

I know I can get deleted rows by using as explained in the [docs](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/wiki/API-Reference-Model#findalloptions-queryoptions---promisearrayinstance)

```
Model.findAll({paranoid: false, where: {deletedAt: {ne: null}}})
```

but paranoid: false isn't available when [updating](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/wiki/API-Reference-Model#updatevalues-options---promisearrayaffectedcountaffectedrows).

Is undeleting soft deleted rows even possible in Sequelize or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `instance.setDataValue('deletedAt', null)`:

```
var Bluebird  = require('bluebird');
var models    = require('./models');

models.sequelize.sync({ force: true })
.then(function () {
  return models.User.create({ name: 'user' })
})
.then(function (user) {
  return user.destroy()
})
.then(function () {
  return models.sequelize.models.User.findAll({ paranoid: false });
})
.then(function (users) {
  var user = users[0];
  user.setDataValue('deletedAt', null);
  return user.save({ paranoid: false });
}).then(function () {
  return models.sequelize.models.User.findAll();
}).then(function (users) {
  console.log(users[0]);
});
```

Please note that this snippet uses Sequelize@v2

Answer (score 22):

Get your object with `{paranoid: false}` option, ie. `var model = Model.findOne({ where: { something: 1 }, paranoid: false })` and then restore it `model.restore()` http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/instance/#restoreoptions-promiseundefined

Comment: That's the only way it worked, although i'd prefer to `setDataValue` since it would mean only one trip to the database in case of a restore+update

Comment: this should be accepted answer. It's the most 'canonical' using a provided API

Answer (score 5):

**You can do this by using `paranoid: false`** :

```
Model.update( { deletedAt: null }, { where: {deletedAt: {ne: null} }, paranoid: false  });
```

> **options.paranoid**
>
> If true, only non-deleted records will be updated. If false, both
>   deleted and non-deleted records will be updated. Only applies if
>   options.paranoid is true for the model.

For more detail : **[DO READ](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-update)**

> I know the question is very old and at that time there might not be
>   the solution

Comment: your answer is useful for someone who just looks this, like me :D , so is that possible to get back data which we deleted? and find it by paranoid true?

Comment: Yes you can do that.

Comment: i was following above code, but not work, i tried deleted one data, and then cant get it back by method above, do u have idea??

Comment: @ZumDummi , you need to define the same thing in model also , read this : http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-definition.html#configuration

Comment: yep i just try to change it, but it said `column "deletedAt" does not exist`, i want to create it now, but what type data for deletedAt column is?

Comment: Have to run model.sync() then

Comment: what is that for?

Comment: sync is not function :(

Comment: Read the doc carefully.

Comment: @VivekDoshi the link to the doc is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use the update method of the instance instead of save. This only worked when adding the `deletedAt` value set `null` in the update data as well.

```
user.setDataValue('deletedAt', null);
user.update({deletedAt:null}, callback);
```

In this case the paranoid option is not necessary in the update.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is not working. You must pass `paranoid: false` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54977491/2430555